# Scroll page effect javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a button that if is pressed, the page scroll to top.
But i want the scroll id made by an animation, can you help me? PS. i prefer javascript than jquery. Thanks.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
            document.body.scrollTop = 0;
            document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }
    }
```

This is my current javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").onclick = function() {
      window.scroll({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth"
      });
  }
}
```